# custom module div id in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 3.0 and T3 Template.

Currently, I can see that each module I created was generated an id automatically, such as id="Mod-141", but I want to give these module divs an id myself when I create them. Is there any way to do this? I will use these ids for some jquery scripting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well there are different ways in which you can achieve this. 
The easiest way is to use Joomla Module Chrome styling ([more info here](http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome)).